# How to log which action method is executed in a controller in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In WebAPI, is there anyway to log the name of the action method for a controller that gets called or executed using an action filter. I am using the RouteData property as shown below, but the action value does not contain any value. Is there any way I can get the action name in the filter.

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        Log(actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.RequestContext.RouteData);

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }

    private void Log(System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRouteData httpRouteData)
    {
        var controllerName = httpRouteData.Values["controller"];

        var actionName = httpRouteData.Values["action"];

        var message = String.Format("controller:{0}, action:{1}", controllerName, actionName);

        Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the action name in the `actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` property (string).

You can also cast that `ActionDescriptor` to `ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor` and obtain an instance of the `MethodInfo` that was called, if you need more information than just string name.

```
 var reflectedActionDescriptor = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor 
       as ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor;
 //inspect reflectedActionDescriptor.MethodInfo here
```