# Stop process in API Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my API's I am extending a custom class (`myClass`) which extends `ApiController`.

What I want to do is in the constructor for `myClass`, compare two values, and if they don't match, then kill the process. Meaning I don't want the functions in the API to actually get hit.

I'd like to return `HttpStatusCode.Forbidden` but I don't want to have to modify existing API functions to check a value that could be set by the controller.

I can't seem to find a good way to kill the request in the constructor and return the `HttpStatusCode` without blocking access to the rest of the API if it's supposed to continue to the requested API function.

Is there a relatively simple approach that could work for this?

Comment: You are looking for [action filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423554/intercept-all-webapi-calls-before-the-route-matching-occurs?lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set Authentication Filter to check that. 
[check more details here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)